# Lexer Implementation in Rust - `PhantomData` Awkwardness

Tags: rust

I've been working on [a Tokeniser/Lexer in Rust](https://github.com/iwillspeak/ullage/blob/syntax-tokens/src/syntax/parse/token_iterator.rs#L8). I would like to have the tokeniser take input from different sources, such as files or in-memory strings. To abstract over this concern i've created a trait `Source`. This has left me with a wonky situation where I *appear* to need a `PhantomData` member in the token iterator. I've created a cut-down example here:

```
/// Source of Characters
///
/// In this example all that a source can do is be sliced to retrieve
/// a subsection of the overall character buffer.
trait Source<'a> {
    /// Character at Offset
    ///
    /// Gets the character at the given offset in the buffer and
    /// returns it. If no character is available at that offset `None`
    /// is returned.
    fn at(&self, offset: usize) -> Option<(char, usize)>;

    /// Slice the Source Buffer
    fn slice(&self, start: usize, end: usize) -> &'a str;
}

/// Source of Characters from a `str` Slice
struct StringSource<'a> {
    pub buff: &'a str
}

/// Implementation of the Source trait.
impl<'a> Source<'a> for StringSource<'a> {
    fn at(&self, offset: usize) -> Option<(char, usize)> {
        self.buff[offset..].chars().nth(0).map(|ch| { (ch, offset + ch.len_utf8()) })
    }

    fn slice(&self, start: usize, end: usize) -> &'a str {
        &self.buff[start..end]
    }
}

/// Token Iterator Implementation
///
/// This token iterator takes a given source and steps through it returning string slices for each token
struct TokenIter<'a, S>
    where S: Source<'a>,
          S: 'a
{
    source: S,
    idx: usize,
    phantom: ::std::marker::PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a, S> TokenIter<'a, S>
    where S: Source<'a>
{
    /// Create a Token Iterator from a Source
    fn new(source: S) -> Self {
        TokenIter {
            source: source,
            idx: 0,
            phantom: ::std::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

/// Token Iterators implement `Iterator`
impl<'a, S> Iterator for TokenIter<'a, S>
    where S: Source<'a>
{
    type Item = &'a str;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let ts = self.idx;
        self.source.at(ts).map(|(_ch, next)| {
            self.idx = next;
            // Imagine a regex state machine is run here to produce a token
            // rather than just returning single-character tokens.
            self.source.slice(ts, next)
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let source = StringSource{ buff: "hello world" };
    let iter = TokenIter::new(source);
    println!("{:?}", iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Run it here:
https://is.gd/OCL91u

Is there a nicer way to express the source buffer lifetime `'a` so that I don't need a `PhantomData` member or this bit of funky lifetime constraints:

```
where S: Source<'a>,
      S: 'a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> such as files or in-memory strings

I'm going to give the advice that people dread: I don't think your abstraction is going to work here. When I first read "in-memory strings", I expected a `String`, not a `&str`. Since you mentioned a file, I think it's still a valid comparison. I don't believe you can implement this trait for such a type:

```
struct OwnedStringSource {
    pub buff: String,
}

impl<'a> Source<'a> for OwnedStringSource {
    fn at(&self, offset: usize) -> Option<(char, usize)> { None }

    fn slice(&self, start: usize, end: usize) -> &'a str {
        // Hmm.... what to put here?
    }
}
```

That is, there's no way to say a reasonable lifetime for `'a`. I also think that it's the same root problem as [Can I write an Iterator that yields a reference into itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25702909/155423).

Aside from that, your original error was probably something like:

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
   --> src/main.rs:117:6
    |
117 | impl<'a, S> Iterator for TokenIter<S>
    |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

The [best advice I've gotten about that specific error](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25041#issuecomment-163116176) was helpful... after thinking about it for a while. Paraphrased and elided for this situation:

> what [the error is] trying to tell you is that it cannot get [the generic type] back from either
>   the implemented trait [...] or the type implemented on [...]. [The where clause]
>   is not enough to extract [the generic] from [the type] because one [...] type can have multiple
>   [...] impls with various arguments

Instead, I might suggest that you [use an associated type instead of the generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/155423):

```
trait Source {
    type Slice;

    fn at(&self, offset: usize) -> Option<(char, usize)>;
    fn slice(&self, start: usize, end: usize) -> Self::Slice;
}
```

This separates the lifetimes from the trait. Specific implementations can still participate in it:

```
impl<'a> Source for StringSource<'a> {
    type Slice = &'a str;
    // ...
}
```

And you can just bubble up the inner type out of the iterator:

```
impl<'a, S> Iterator for TokenIter<S>
    where S: Source,
{
    type Item = S::Slice;
    // ...
}
```

You potentially might need to add extra bounds on that generic there (`S::Slice: AsRef<str>`) depending on what you need to be able to do with the slice in the iterator implementation.

---

```
trait Source {
    type Slice;

    fn at(&self, offset: usize) -> Option<(char, usize)>;
    fn slice(&self, start: usize, end: usize) -> Self::Slice;
}

struct StringSource<'a> {
    pub buff: &'a str
}

impl<'a> Source for StringSource<'a> {
    type Slice = &'a str;

    fn at(&self, offset: usize) -> Option<(char, usize)> {
        self.buff[offset..].chars().nth(0).map(|ch| { (ch, offset + ch.len_utf8()) })
    }

    fn slice(&self, start: usize, end: usize) -> &'a str {
        &self.buff[start..end]
    }
}

struct TokenIter<S> {
    source: S,
    idx: usize,
}

impl<S> TokenIter<S> {
    fn new(source: S) -> Self {
        TokenIter {
            source: source,
            idx: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl<S> Iterator for TokenIter<S>
    where S: Source,
{
    type Item = S::Slice;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let ts = self.idx;
        self.source.at(ts).map(|(_ch, next)| {
            self.idx = next;
            self.source.slice(ts, next)
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let source = StringSource{ buff: "hello world" };
    let iter = TokenIter::new(source);
    println!("{:?}", iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd rather be told that it's the wrong abstraction by you now than find out further down the line. I knew I was dealing with the lifetime of the slice wrong; I just didn't know what the correct solution was.

I think i'll go for a type parameter on the `Source` interface with the `AsRef<str>` restriction on it. Tokens produced from that source can then use that same tactic to expose the captured lexemes to higher levels.